# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm new in node and react and facing this error

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
at model.Query.exec (D:\Amazon Clone MERN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4540:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Amazon Clone MERN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4639:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

I'm fetching single product from mongo db with _id but it says id is undefined;

I want this url when click on single product

```
http://localhost:3000/api/products/6155eb0085a43d3dfa5e2f74
```

but i get this url

```
http://localhost:3000/api/products/undefined
```

my productRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Product = require('../models/ProductModel');
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');

const router = express.Router();

//single product route
router.get('/products/:id', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
    if (product) {
        res.json(product);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({message: 'Product not found'});
    }
}));

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
 const express = require('express');
require('colors');
const products = require('./data/products');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const productRoutes = require('./routes/productsRoute');

//dotenv config
dotenv.config();
const {connectDb} = require('./config/config')
connectDb();
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Welcome to Node server</h1>')
});

app.use('/api', productRoutes);

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${process.env.PORT}`.inverse.green)
})
```

ProductDetails.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
//import Product from '../products';
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import {Row, Col, ListGroup, Button, Image, ListGroupItem} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const ProductDetails = ({match}) => {
    console.log(match);
    //const product = Product.find((p) => p.id === match.params.id);
    const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProduct = async () => {
            const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
            setProduct(data);
        }
        fetchProduct();
    },[match]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> &nbsp;GO BACK</Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid/>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                        <ListGroupItem>
                            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem>
                            <Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}></Rating>
                        </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem>
                            Price: ${product.price}
                        </ListGroupItem>
                        <ListGroupItem>
                            {product.description}
                        </ListGroupItem>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroupItem>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>Status: </Col>
                            <Col>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In stock' : 'Out of stock'} </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                    <ListGroupItem>
                        <Button className="btn-block" Type="Button">Add to cart</Button>
                    </ListGroupItem>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

i console match it says id is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-router-dom v6, you need to use **useParams** instead of match prop.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-params#useparams

ProductDetails.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
//import Product from '../products';
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Button,
  Image,
  ListGroupItem,
} from 'react-bootstrap'

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams()
  console.log(id)
  //const product = Product.find((p) => p.id === match.params.id);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
      setProduct(data)
    }
    fetchProduct()
  }, [id])

  return (
    <div>
      <Link to='/' className='btn btn-light'>
        <i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i> &nbsp;GO BACK
      </Link>
      <Row>
        <Col md={6}>
          <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroupItem>
              <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            </ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>
              <Rating
                value={product.rating}
                text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
              ></Rating>
            </ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroupItem>
            <ListGroupItem>{product.description}</ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <Col md={3}>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <Row>
              <Col>Status: </Col>
              <Col>
                {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In stock' : 'Out of stock'}{' '}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </ListGroupItem>
          <ListGroupItem>
            <Button className='btn-block' Type='Button'>
              Add to cart
            </Button>
          </ListGroupItem>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```